# Jar to Android - Java

Tags: java, android, jar

He querido buscar algun **apk** que pueda Empaquetar un archivo java a Jar para Ejecutarlo en un **Emulador**.

He intentado Instalar Eclipse en un Emulador pero no es Compatible, no se si hay un Programa sencillo para Empaquetar.

**Crear un empaquetado para Ejecutar**

No se si hay otras Formas, pero no se Cuales quiero saberlas Solo quiero empaquetar **Jar** en **Android**.

Quiero respuestas...

Comment: Creo que esta pregunta no es específicamente de programación. Se me ocurre que puedes descargar OpenJDK en [Termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-app) con el comando `pkg install openjdk-17`. Deberías tener acceso a la mayoría de herramientas del JDK.

Comment: @Mateo y que comando tengo que colocar para empaquetar no encuentro una Documentacion... ):

Comment: Todo lo que puedes hacer mediante la interfaz también lo puedes hacer por línea de comandos pero desconozco cómo. Sugiero que edites la pregunta "¿Cómo puedo empaquetar un jar por línea de comandos?"  o lo que toque.

Comment: Gracias Bro, (---:

Comment: Bienvenido, recuerda agregar lo que investigaste o trataste, agrega más información, un .apk ya es un "empaquetado", tal vez te refieres a poder usar un .jar en una app. Revisa [ask], saludos.